# How can I sell add-ons on the G Suite Marketplace?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I use some Google Sheet add-ons for which I need to pay for. Now, I would like to publish and sell Google Sheets add-ons myself but I could not find any documentation from Google on how this can be done.

Comment: Did you find some info that you can share?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot sell add-on on the Google marketplace by default. If you want to sell, you'll need to build a payment system that will handle user payments records and other related information. Your add-on will communicate with your custom payment API to check user payment status and offer services accordingly.